# How to highligt wrongly written code in visual studio code, when using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

Say I have this code in a file called myfile.js

```
const item1 = "A"

console.log(item1)

console.log(item2)
```

If i run the js file with node .\myfile.js , I first get the print of item1 ("A"), then it crashes, as it should, because item2 is not defined.

Before I used to get a red highlight that would warn me if a variable does not exist, in Visual studio code, but now for some reason it does not show me anymore.

What are the necessary steps I need to take to make it highlight wrongly written syntax again?

Googling this I mostly find that this can be solved by using the Esling extension, but for me it does not work. What can I do? I really want to keep using vs code.

I currently have no other extensions installed

my settings.json file looks like this

```
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also have material-icon-theme extension installed and prettier, but that is it.

Comment: https://dev.to/chgldev/getting-prettier-eslint-and-vscode-to-work-together-3678

Comment: @Quentin That got my prettier setup and working, thanks, but It did not solve my problem. I still do not get error highlights in code.

Comment: For anyone seeking a solution, I found this and it helps.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript

Comment: can you try starting the app with node -c app.js for example?

Comment: No I can't. But I do not really see what that has to do with my issue.